# Why don't call method presentationControllerForPresentedViewController of UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios8-extension

I want use custom UIPresentationController.
For it when I want show new scene I call this code

```
UIViewController *cv = [[...]];

cv.transitionManager=[[MyTransition alloc] init];
cv.transitioningDelegate=actionSheet.transitionManager;
cv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

[self presentViewController:cv animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

my transition manager has methods:

```
#pragma mark - UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceController:(UIViewController *)source{
    return self;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed{
    return self;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForPresentation:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator{
    return  nil;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForDismissal:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator{
    return self;
}


- (UIPresentationController *)presentationControllerForPresentedViewController:(UIViewController *)presented presentingViewController:(UIViewController *)presenting sourceViewController:(UIViewController *)source {
    MyPresentationController *presentationController = [[MyPresentationController alloc] initWithPresentedViewController:presented presentingViewController:presenting];
    return presentationController;
}
```

**but the method presentationControllerForPresentedViewController doesn't call!**

**Why?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It will be called only if your present a view controller using the `UIModalPresentationCustom` presentation style

Comment: he is using UIModalPresentationCustom

Comment: @litso indeed. I don't know how I missed that and why my answer wast accepted then. It is possible that author implemented UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate methods, but did not conformed to this protocol.

Answer (score 9):

`modalPresentationStyle` instead of `modalTransitionStyle` is a correct answer :)

Comment: Wow, I have been working with custom transitions for a while and sometimes things got weird and I did not know why. There are modalPresentationStyle and modalTransitionStyle ...

Comment: May god bless you and your family for helping me find this stupid mistake.